# Sorting is not working in realm db in my application

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-database

Im new in realm db. I completed add and get data in realm db. But, I couldn't sort(ascending and descending).Im my code it display items in listview. Listview contains 5 list and each list contains 4 field(name, age, skill and date). if I sort(ascending) name, need to ascending in 5 list.My code is not work 
I post my code here,

```
 private void Ascending_order() {

    realm.beginTransaction();


  RealmResults<Employee> result = realm.where(Employee.class)
            .sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
    realm.copyFromRealm(result);
    realm.commitTransaction();
    employeedetailadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Adapter class:

```
  public class EmployeeDetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Employee>employeeDetaillists = new ArrayList<>();
private Context c;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private OnItemClick mCallback;
private SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");



public EmployeeDetailAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Employee> employeeDetaillists, OnItemClick listener) {
    this.employeeDetaillists = employeeDetaillists;
this.c= c;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mCallback = listener;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employeeDetaillists.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return employeeDetaillists.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
Holder holder;

if (v==null){
    v= (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_item,null);
    holder = new Holder();
    holder.tvPersonName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
    holder.tvPersonAge = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonAge);
    holder.tvPersonSkill = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonSkill);
    holder.ivEditPesonDetail=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivEditPesonDetail);
    holder.tvPersondate=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersondate);
    holder.ivDeletePerson=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivDeletePerson);
    v.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
}
holder.tvPersonName.setText(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getName());
holder.tvPersonAge.setText(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getAge());
holder.tvPersonSkill.setText(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getSkill());
    String strDate = df.format(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getSdate());
holder.tvPersondate.setText(strDate);

holder.ivDeletePerson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Delete(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getName(),position);

    }
});

return v;
}

private void Delete(String name, int position) {
    mCallback.onClickdelete(name, position);
}

public void updateData(RealmResults<Employee> result) {

}


class Holder {
    TextView tvPersonName, tvPersonAge, tvPersonSkill,tvPersondate;
    ImageView ivDeletePerson, ivEditPesonDetail;
}
```

}

Comment: Collections.sort(data); is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does't change db. You just get sorted items but don't use them.

```
realm.copyFromRealm(result); // this line does nothing
realm.commitTransaction(); // this one too, because you change nothing
employeedetailadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // you data is the same, so this line also useless here
```

To see your data sorted you should use `RealmResults` in your adapter. With this approach your list always will sorted, even after adding new items. But note: your adapter should extends `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.

You should run this code before creating adapter and use `result` inside adapter:

```
RealmResults<Employee> result = realm.where(Employee.class)
        .sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
```

---

Also you can try manually update data of your adapter.

```
private void Ascending_order() {
    RealmResults<Employee> result = realm.where(Employee.class)
            .sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
    employeedetailadapter.updateData(result); // update data inside adapter before calling `notifyDataSetChanged`
    employeedetailadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

You need to create `updateData` method yourself:

```
public void updateData(RealmResults<Employee> result) {
    employeeDetaillists = new ArrayList<Employee>(result);
}
```

Comment: Im showing  added items  in listview. when I click buttton(button name is ascending) , listview display ascending and descending order(if click descending order button).

Comment: @Ana I've updated my answer to show another approach.

Comment: Thanks. but  employeedetailadapter.updateData(result);  ... In this "updateData" is not set with adapter.

Comment: @Ana Yes, you should create this method.

Comment: I create "updatedata" method in adapter. Inside this method, what i need write? can u please help me? public void updateData(RealmResults<Employee> result) {
        
    }

Comment: @Ana To answer exactly I need to see code of your adapter.

Comment: I upload my adapter class . Can you please check and update me?

Comment: Thanks. But this code doesn't work. it show empty listview

Comment: @Ana Are you see empty list after button click or all time?

Comment: After button click list display empty. Now i find where the problem occur.

     private void Ascending_order() {

      
        RealmResults<Employee> result = realm.where(Employee.class).findAll();
        result = result.sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING); //  i get result size is 0 here //

        employeedetailadapter.updateData(result);
        employeedetailadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     
    }

Comment: @Any Do you have any idea why `result` is empty?

Comment: No. Can You tell me the solution. This is my POJO CLASS . 
public class Employee extends RealmObject {
PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    Required
    public String name,age,skill;

Comment: @Ana You need to do some experiments and look how app reacts to changes. For a start try remove `.sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING)`. `result` should not be empty, you should figure out where is bug.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, while getting data from Realm you don't need to write it in Transaction. Write Transaction is required only when you are adding data in realm or updating any realm object.

And about your problem, To get sorted data from realm, You can do it like this

```
RealmResults<Employee> result = realm.where(Employee.class).sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
```

Now the data you got is sorted, If you still see wrong order in your ListView then there could be some issue in your Adapter. If you share your adapter code, then I can help further :)

Updated:

Adapter Class

```
  public class EmployeeDetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private RealmResults<Employee> employeeDetaillists;
    private Context c;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private OnItemClick mCallback;
    private SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");



    public EmployeeDetailAdapter(Context c,RealmResults<Employee> employeeDetaillists, OnItemClick listener) {
        this.employeeDetaillists = employeeDetaillists;
        this.c= c;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mCallback = listener;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return employeeDetaillists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return employeeDetaillists.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Holder holder;

        if (v==null){
            v= (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_item,null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.tvPersonName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
            holder.tvPersonAge = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonAge);
            holder.tvPersonSkill = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonSkill);
            holder.ivEditPesonDetail=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivEditPesonDetail);
            holder.tvPersondate=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPersondate);
            holder.ivDeletePerson=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivDeletePerson);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvPersonName.setText(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvPersonAge.setText(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getAge());
        holder.tvPersonSkill.setText(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getSkill());
        String strDate = df.format(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getSdate());
        holder.tvPersondate.setText(strDate);

        holder.ivDeletePerson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Delete(employeeDetaillists.get(position).getName(),position);

            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    private void Delete(String name, int position) {
        mCallback.onClickdelete(name, position);
    }

    public void updateData(RealmResults<Employee> result) {

    }


    class Holder {
        TextView tvPersonName, tvPersonAge, tvPersonSkill,tvPersondate;
        ImageView ivDeletePerson, ivEditPesonDetail;
    }
}
```

In your Activity please change following function

```
 private void Ascending_order() {
      result = realm.where(Employee.class)
           .sort("name", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
     employeedetailadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

"result" list should be declared on class level and should be passed to Adapter's constructor as well.

Like

```
    class Activity {
      RealmResults<Employee> result;
      EmployeeDetailAdapter employeedetailadapter;

      //// Other Code

        public onCreate(Bundle b) {
         result = realm.where(Employee.class).findAll();
               employeedetailadapter = new EmployeeDetailAdapter(this, result, listener);

          // Other code
         }
   }
```

Comment: I upload my adapter class . Can you please check and update me?

Comment: Change ArrayList to RealmResults in your Adapter everywhere. I updated my answer.

Comment: Check my latest updated answer, it should work now. Please vote and accept my answer if it works. Thanks.